Why we are unable to scan the tags (get list of the tags) using Pycomm3 from a LogixController Simulator?
I have simulated control logix simulator using cpppo with 5 tags. But when client request for get_tag_list() it is throwing an error.
Thread-2 enip.dev ERROR    request    EtherNet/IP CIP error at 14 total bytes:
b'U\x02 k$\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x08\x00'
----------------------------------------------^ (byte 14)

Please help me how I can scan the control logix simulator to get the tags list.
